# Finding an div in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

this is what i am working on this is a rough design and now sure it will come when i post it.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------

first name goes here.....
---------------------------------------------------------------------
datetime                                          buttons
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the below code works if using with `tr` but now i am using the `divs` what exaclty do i need to put, `div id`?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSave(obj) {
        debugger
            // Find the row this button is in
            var tr = $(obj).closest("tr");
            // Get the value from the edit control
            var firstNameEdit = tr.find("[id*='firstNameEdit']").val();
            // assign value to hidden input
            tr.find("[id*='firstNameHidden']").val(firstNameEdit);
            var lastNameEdit = tr.find("[id*='lastNameEdit']").val();
            tr.find("[id*='lastNameHidden']").val(lastNameEdit);
        }
    </script>
```

here is my new html code with div:

```
<div class='columns'>
<div class='subj'> 
<div id="container">
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="firstNameEditPlaceholder" />
      <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="firstNameHidden" visible="false" />
<br />
 <br />
 <div id="left"></div>
 <!-- left -->
 <div id="right"></div>
 <!-- right -->
 <div class="clear">
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- container -->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your table format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i able to get:

```
var _name = $("#[id*='firstNameHidden']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
        var tr = $(obj).closest("tr");

       //change to

        var tr = $(obj).closest("div");
```

Comment: when i debug the code this is what i get `undefined` instead of the value of a textbox (input)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#firstNameHidden').val($('#firstNameEditPlaceholder').val());
```

Comment: I suspect ASP is adding its own things to the IDs. Try this: $('[id*=firstNameHidden]').val($('[id*=firstNameEditPlaceholder]').val());

Comment: you are correct, when i looked at the source of the page this is what i get the id `<textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$ContentMain$viewcomments$rpt$ctl01$firstNameEdit"`